# ORDER BY not functioning in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I'm having difficulty with some SQL syntax within a stored procedure.  I'm retrieving the most recent row from a SQL table (in *SQL Server Management Studio*), and using it later on in my stored procedure.  That's why I'm setting variables (ie: `@firstname, @lastname`, etc..).  I'm only interested in the most recent row based on the `dbo.[ws_test_request].CREATED` column value.  I need the variables set based on the data queried, so I need to get the *"This doesn't work"* query working.

*PS: the "2011051001" will be a variable... I'm just trying to get it to work.*

**This works:**

```
SELECT 
    TOP 1
    @firstname = [sample_donor_firstname],
    @lastname = [sample_donor_lasttname],
    @middlename = [sample_donor_middlename]
FROM dbo.[ws_test_request]
WHERE 
    [sample_specimen_id] = '2011051001'
ORDER BY dbo.[ws_test_request].created DESC
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
SELECT 
    TOP 1
    [sample_donor_firstname],
    [sample_donor_lasttname],
    [sample_donor_middlename]
FROM dbo.[ws_test_request]
WHERE 
    [sample_specimen_id] = '2011051001'
ORDER BY dbo.[ws_test_request].created DESC
```

Thank you!!

Comment: I'm declaring my variables above the query.

 DECLARE 
  @donorid INT,
  @firstname NVARCHAR(255),
  @lastname NVARCHAR(255),
  @identifyingnumber NVARCHAR(255),  -- SSN/MRN
  @middlename NVARCHAR(255),
  @comment NVARCHAR(1023);

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? What do you expect it to do? Do you expect it to set the variables eventhough you don't set the variables in the query?

Comment: The only difference appears to be that you're not assigning the variables in the second query; so if that's what you want to happen, then you'll need to use the first query... what am I missing?

Comment: Hi guys, I must need glasses.  The ORDER BY was getting the red underlines because I had a semi-colon in my previous code, and then added the ORDER BY clause.  So the command was ended before the ORDER BY.  You are completely correct.  There was nothing wrong with my code.  When I put the code "This doesn't work" I never tested that.  I just set my variable (that replaced the 2011051001" value before my query, so my variable still had the semi-colon.  When I wrote it in Stack Overflow, I replaced the variable in the query with the value to prevent confusion.

Example:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hi guys, I must need glasses.**

SELECT

TOP 1

@firstname = [sample_donor_firstname],

@lastname = [sample_donor_lasttname],

@middlename = [sample_donor_middlename]

FROM dbo.[ws_test_request]

WHERE

[client_id] = @clientid

AND [sample_specimen_id] = @sample_identifyingnumber; -- <============= BAD!!

ORDER BY dbo.[ws_test_request].created DESC

**When I tested it with the "2011051001" value, I had set @sample_identifyingnumber to "2011051001" although I still had the semi-colon.  That's what caused my ORDER BY clause to fail, and get the red underlines.  There was nothing wrong with my code in my question.  But thanks for the ideas of using cursors!  I learned SQL in college, but haven't used it much in 5 years.  So thanks for the ideas.**

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your second query. If you want to use the results on a later point you can use your first query or use declare a cursor:

```
DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT 
    TOP 1
    [sample_donor_firstname],
    [sample_donor_lasttname],
    [sample_donor_middlename]
FROM dbo.[ws_test_request]
WHERE 
    [sample_specimen_id] = '2011051001'
ORDER BY dbo.[ws_test_request].created DESC
```

and then open & fetch results:

```
OPEN MyCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @firstname, @lastname, @middlename
```

Comment: You don't need a cursor for this - just simply setting the variable (like how OP stated) is good enough since he is only selecting TOP 1

Comment: @M.R.: I know, but I told him there are 2 possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Your first query seems correct - the second query is not actually setting the variables, so you just need to put the variables in there...

```
DECLARE @donorid INT, 
@firstname NVARCHAR(255), 
@lastname NVARCHAR(255), 
@identifyingnumber NVARCHAR(255), -- SSN/MRN 
@middlename NVARCHAR(255), 
@comment NVARCHAR(1023


SELECT       
TOP 1      
@firstname = [sample_donor_firstname],      
@lastname = [sample_donor_lasttname],      
@middlename = [sample_donor_middlename]  
FROM dbo.[ws_test_request]  
WHERE       
[sample_specimen_id] = '2011051001'  
ORDER BY dbo.[ws_test_request].created DESC 

-- and then select the results (or use them wherever else you want to use them)
Select @firstname as FirstName, @lastname as LastName, @middlename as MiddleName
```